# jsfml, poolEvents() method

Tags: java, jsfml

I recently started project in java using the `JSFML` library. My code fragment looks like this:

```
Iterable<Event> events;
events = mRenderWindow.pollEvents();
mKeyboardListener.handleEvents(events);
mMouseListener.handleEvents(events);
```

My problem is, when I firstly use `KeyboardListener`, then `MouseListener` is not working and vice versa. Can someone explain this behaviour? I searched for some info and there is not enough explanation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should make a copy of the events if you hope to iterate through them multiple times, this is because jsfml specifies a custom iterator.